# matplotlib: synchronize pan/zoom events across multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have multiple subplots mirror the pan/rotate/zoom mouse events in any of the subplots. Specifically, I have multiple 3D subplots and I would like a rotation/zoom in any of them to be synchronized across all of the 3D subplots. Is there an "easy" way to accomplish this?

Comment: For 2D plots, you can use axis sharing, not sure off the top of my head if it will work for 3D.

Comment: It doesn't work for 3D plots.

Comment: I assume then that one way is to set up a system of event connections that somehow mirrors the mouse events over one figure in all other figures, or override the built-in connections with ones that keep the rotation/zoom states of all subfigures synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave an answer to a similar question,

[Using Matplotlib 3D axes, how to drag two axes at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167196/using-matplotlib-3d-axes-how-to-drag-two-axes-at-once/41190487)

without knowing this question existed. The idea is to register event listeners to synchronize two or more axes.