# Pyplot - Share axis between 3D subplots

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, axes

I'm trying to create two 3D suplots side-by-side that I can easily compare visually. I'd like to be able to link their axes so that when I rotate, translate or zoom on one of them in pyplot's interactive graph, the other one will rotate, translate or zoom the same way. 
I tried telling the figure to share(xyz) like I would have done in a 2D plot but they aren't doing what I expect. They don't seem to be linked. Can someone help?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import get_test_data

# Twice as wide as it is tall.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

#---- First subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax1.set_zlim3d(-1.01, 1.01)

#---- Second subplot that I want to share axis with first subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d',sharex = ax1,sharey = ax1,sharez = ax1)
surf2 = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the answer provided to this question:

- [Using Matplotlib 3D axes, how to drag two axes at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167196/using-matplotlib-3d-axes-how-to-drag-two-axes-at-once/41190487#41190487)

Just to provide a full working solution here:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm


# Twice as wide as it is tall.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

#---- First subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax1.set_zlim3d(-1.01, 1.01)

#---- Second subplot that I want to share axis with first subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
surf2 = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax1:
        if ax1.button_pressed in ax1._rotate_btn:
            ax2.view_init(elev=ax1.elev, azim=ax1.azim)
        elif ax1.button_pressed in ax1._zoom_btn:
            ax2.set_xlim3d(ax1.get_xlim3d())
            ax2.set_ylim3d(ax1.get_ylim3d())
            ax2.set_zlim3d(ax1.get_zlim3d())
    elif event.inaxes == ax2:
        if ax2.button_pressed in ax2._rotate_btn:
            ax1.view_init(elev=ax2.elev, azim=ax2.azim)
        elif ax2.button_pressed in ax2._zoom_btn:
            ax1.set_xlim3d(ax2.get_xlim3d())
            ax1.set_ylim3d(ax2.get_ylim3d())
            ax1.set_zlim3d(ax2.get_zlim3d())
    else:
        return
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

c1 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

Comment: so why not mark the Q as a duplicate? or paste the relevant info here? Link-only answers are frowned upon here at SO.

Comment: @tom I thought about it, but the linked question does not ask about zooming. Only the answer is taking zooming into account.