# Matplotlib - Extract 2D contour of a 3D polygons plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, geometry, contour

I have a 3D plot defined by a set of Poly3DCollection. Each polygon of the collection holds a list of 3D simplices (a simplex = 4 points) like the following.

```
[[[21096.4, 15902.1, 74.3],  
  [21098.5, 15904.3, 54.7],
  [21114.2, 15910.1, 63.0],
  [21096.4, 15902.1, 74.3]],
  ...
 [[21096.4, 15902.1, 74.3],
  [21114.8, 15909.9, 91.3],
  [21114.2, 15910.1, 63.0],
  [21096.4, 15902.1, 74.3]]]
```

From theses collections, I plot a 3D mesh giving me this result
[image: 3D mesh plotting]

I would like to determine the contour of this 3D mesh when projected on 2D for plotting it on a screen, in order to highlight it. 
Ideally it would give me something like
[image]

**Is there any way to achieve this ?**

To achieve it I was thinking about something like

1. Getting the 2D coordinates of my 3D points once projected on the visualization plane, by multiplying each point by a projection matrix that matplotlib must have internally for final rendering
   **OR** 
   directly get the projected 2D coordinates from matplotlib internals, by I don't know if it is possible.
2. Applying some kind of 2D contour detection algorithm to the 2D coordinates from step 1
3. Add the 2D contour found at step 2 to the existing 3D plot

However I don't find any way to implement this contour detection from the interface exposed by my matplotlib Axes3D object.

As long as I can achieve plotting the 2D contour, it doesn't matter to me if I determine it directly on my original 3D dataset and the projection or from my matplotlib Axes3D object.

Comment: Would a background shading be good enough? In this case you could adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905949/2454357) to your needs. If not, I could imagine a solution involving shapely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be much more complicated than I at first anticipated. The way I solved it was to first rotate the object into a frontal view (in terms of the `Axes3D` `elev` and `azim` angles), projected it onto the y-z-plane, compute the 2D outline, re-add the third dimension and then rotating the now 3D outline back into the current view.

The rotation part can be accomplished with simple matrix operation, one only has to take care that the x, y, and z axes may be stretched and need to be un-stretched before rotation.

The projection part was a bit tricky, as I don't know of any clever way to find the outer points of such a large collection of points. I therefore solved it by calculating the projection of each simplex separately, compute their 2D convex hulls (using `scipy`), convert them into `shapely` polygons, and finally compute the union of all these polygons. I then added back the missing x-coordinate and rotated the entire thing back into the current view.

By default, `Axes3D` objects use perspective, causes the actual outline of the object to not align perfectly with the computed projection. This can be avoided by using an orthogonal view (set with `ax.set_proj_type('ortho')`).

Finally, once the image is rotated, the outline/projection needs to be updated. I therefore added the entire function to the event queue following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41190487/2454357).

Please ask if there are any further questions.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

##the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

##generating some random points:
points = np.random.rand(50,3)
xmin,xmax = 0,100
ymin,ymax = -10,10
zmin,zmax = -20,20
points[:,1] = (points[:,1]*(ymax-ymin)+ymin) * np.sin(points[:,0]*np.pi)
points[:,2] = (points[:,2]*(zmax-zmin)+zmin) * np.sin(points[:,0]*np.pi)
points[:,0] *= 100


##group them into simlices
tri =  Delaunay(points)
simplex_coords = np.array([tri.points[simplex] for simplex in tri.simplices])

##plotting the points
ax.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], points[:,2])

##visualizing simplices
line_coords = np.array(
    [[c[i],c[j]] for c in simplex_coords for i in range(len(c)) for j in range(i+1,len(c))]
)
simplex_lines = Line3DCollection(line_coords, colors='k', linewidths=1, zorder=10)
ax.add_collection3d(simplex_lines)    

##adjusting plot
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylim([2*ymin,2*ymax])
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlim([2*zmin,2*zmax])
ax.set_zlabel('z')


def compute_2D_outline():
    """
    Compute the outline of the 2D projection of the 3D mesh and display it as
    a Poly3DCollection or a Line3DCollection.
    """

    global collection
    global lines
    global elev
    global azim

    ##remove the previous projection (if it has been already created)
    try:
        collection.remove()
        lines.remove()
    except NameError as e:
        pass


    ##storing current axes orientation
    elev = ax.elev
    azim = ax.azim

    ##convert angles
    theta = -ax.elev*np.pi/180
    phi = -ax.azim*np.pi/180

    #the extend of each of the axes:
    diff = lambda t: t[1]-t[0]
    lx = diff(ax.get_xlim())
    ly = diff(ax.get_ylim())
    lz = diff(ax.get_zlim())

    ##to compute the projection, we 'unstretch' the axes and rotate them
    ##into the (elev=0, azmi=0) orientation
    stretch = np.diag([1/lx,1/ly,1/lz])
    rot_theta = np.array([
        [np.cos(theta), 0, -np.sin(theta)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [np.sin(theta), 0,  np.cos(theta)],
    ])
    rot_phi = np.array([
        [np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi), 0],
        [np.sin(phi),  np.cos(phi), 0],
        [0,0,1],
    ])
    rot_tot = np.dot(rot_theta,np.dot(rot_phi,stretch))

    ##after computing the outline, we will have to reverse this operation:
    bstretch = np.diag([lx,ly,lz])
    brot_theta = np.array([
        [ np.cos(theta), 0, np.sin(theta)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [-np.sin(theta), 0, np.cos(theta)],
    ])
    brot_phi = np.array([
        [ np.cos(phi),  np.sin(phi), 0],
        [-np.sin(phi),  np.cos(phi), 0],
        [0,0,1],
    ])
    brot_tot = np.dot(np.dot(bstretch,brot_phi),brot_theta)

    ##To get the exact outline, we will have to compute the projection of each simplex
    ##separately and compute the convex hull of the projection. We then use shapely to
    ##compute the unity of all these convex hulls to get the projection (or shadow).
    poly = None
    for simplex in simplex_coords:
        simplex2D = np.dot(rot_tot,simplex.T)[1:].T
        hull = simplex2D[ConvexHull(simplex2D).vertices]
        if poly is None:
            poly = Polygon(hull)
        else:
            poly = poly.union(Polygon(hull))

    ##the 2D points of the final projection have to be made 3D and transformed back
    ##into the correct axes rotation
    outer_points2D = np.array(poly.exterior.coords.xy)
    outer_points3D = np.concatenate([[np.zeros(outer_points2D.shape[1])],outer_points2D])    
    outer_points3D_orig = np.dot(brot_tot, outer_points3D)

    ##adding the polygons
    collection = Poly3DCollection(
        [outer_points3D_orig.T], alpha=0.25, facecolor='b', zorder=-1
    )
    ax.add_collection3d(collection)

    ##adding the lines
    lines = Line3DCollection(
        [outer_points3D_orig.T], alpha=0.5, colors='r', linewidths=5, zorder=5
    )
    ax.add_collection3d(lines)    


def on_move(event):
    """
    For tracking rotations of the Axes3D object
    """

    if event.inaxes == ax and (elev != ax.elev or azim != ax.azim):
        compute_2D_outline()        
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

##initial outline:
compute_2D_outline()

##the entire thing will only work correctly with an orthogonal view
ax.set_proj_type('ortho')

##saving ax.azim and ax.elev for on_move function
azim = ax.azim
elev = ax.elev

##adding on_move to the event queue
c1 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

The final result (with some generated random data) looks something like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try it this week !

Comment: @FloW did you get it to work? If not, please let me know -- this was really interesting and I'd like to get it to work properly...

Comment: unfortunately I didn't have yet the possibility to test it yet, sometimes urgent stuff has to pass before other urgent stuff... but I'll definitely get back to it before January. In any case I'll let you know !

Just to let you know, I noticed that the projection matrix of the current view of a 3D figure can be accessed by using [Axes.get_proj](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.get_proj)
This will avoid having to reconstruct it from the elev and azimut

Comment: I finally took some time to port your proposition of implementation inside the piece of software I develop. 

I rewrapped the globals to something more modular and it works at the functional level, unfortunately the performance overhead is too heavy for interactivity.

I didn't specify the full specs:
I'm plotting [1000:100000] points acquired from biological microstructures, and it's rather exploratory so interactivity matters.
Also, the data is not convex and can be disjoint so poly can become a MultiPolygon.

Thanks again for your great insight :)

Comment: Here is a gist of my implementation https://gist.github.com/flowernert/f392cd9fbdc44604df9567227504b329

Comment: @FloW looks really good. If you find no other ways to boost performance, you could try compiling the code with numba.

Comment: I'm rather thinking of going toward showing my data using a GPU-based solution, I did a prototype with Vispy a month ago, maybe I'll take some time to develop it fully in order to get away from matplotlib for my visualization.